# how can i append in reverse? python

Tags: python

`.append` 
Function adds elements to the list.
How can I add elements to the list? In reverse? So that index zero is new value, and the old values move up in index?
What append does

```
[a,b,c,d,e]
```

what I would like.

```
[e,d,c,b,a]
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I've noticed that you've asked a few questions that look very suspiciously like homework… So before answering this, please tell us: what have you done to try and solve this on your own?

Comment: spend 15 hours googling thing. what about you, how was your day?

Comment: Well, sure — if you're googling "thing", you're unlikely to find any useful Python-related results :) But, more seriously: in the future, check out the documentation pages for the built-in types. For example, googling "Python list" yields http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html as the top result, which has the information you're after.

Comment: well my instructor told me to google "in"

Comment: you can also just reverse the list when your done if you want.  mylist.reverse()  will reverse the list inplace.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Suppose you have a list `a`, `a = [1, 2, 3]`

Now suppose you wonder what kinds of things you can do to that list:

```
dir(a)
```

Hmmmm... wonder what this `insert` thingy does...

```
help(a.insert)
```

Insert object before index, you say? Why, that sounds a lot like what I want to do! If I want to insert something at the beginning of the list, that would be *before* index 0. What object do I want to insert? Let's try 7...

```
a.insert(0, 7)
print a
```

Well, look at that 7 right at the front of the list!

TL;DR: `dir()` will let you see what's available, `help()` will show you how it works, and then you can play around with it and see what it does, or Google up some documentation since you now know what the feature you want is called.

Answer (score 12):

It would be more efficient to use a [`deque`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque)(double-ended queue) for this. Inserting at index 0 is extremely costly in lists since each element must be shifted over which requires O(N) running time, in a `deque` the same operation is O(1).

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> x = deque()
>>> x.appendleft('a')
>>> x.appendleft('b')
>>> x
deque(['b', 'a'])
```

Answer (score 6):

Using Python's list `insert` command with 0 for the position value will insert the value at the head of the list, thus inserting in reverse order:

```
your_list.insert(0, new_item)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `somelist.insert(0, item)` to place `item` at the beginning of `somelist`, shifting all other elements down.  Note that for large lists this is a *very expensive* operation.  Consider using [deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#deque-objects) instead if you will be adding items to or removing items from both ends of the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
your_list=['New item!!']+your_list
```

But the insert method works as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
lst=["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
lst_rev=[]
lst_rev.append(lst[::-1])
print(lst_rev)
```

Comment: As a nice touch, add the output!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to add elements in a list in reverse order:

```
liste1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
liste2 = list()
for i in liste1:
    liste2.insert(0,i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following (assuming x is what you want to prepend):

```
your_list = [x] + your_list
```

or:

```
your_list.insert(0, x)
```